# Linux Mint не влазит в окно VirtualBox (Windows 7). Как убрать полосы прокрутки?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-7, virtualbox, linux-mint

Запускаю VirtualBox (в Windows 7) с установленным Linux Mint и вижу вот такие полосы прокрутки. Т.е. Linux Mint не влазит в окно VirtualBox.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал (в меню VirtualBox)

```
Устройство - Подключить образ диска дополнительной гостевой ОС
```

и (в терминале)

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Не помогло.

Как исправить?

P.S.
Когда устанавливал, то в окне [BootCD](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=191) пришлось выбрать "**Start in compatibility mode**", т.к. в обычном режиме не мог установить (пробовал по 2 раза на рабочем ПК и домашнем ноуте) - установка не завершалась до конца (выдавало ошибку).

Comment: А у меня с самого начала работало.

Comment: Ответ нужно писать в ответе, а не в вопросе

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт? Писать в комментарии к ответу.

Comment: @Linuxoid, не могу дать ошибку уже. Проблема решилась увеличением объема диска для гостевой ОС до 25 гб.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменил размер жесткого диска (в VirtualBox) до 25 гб и переустановил Linux Mint (в обычном режиме, а ***не*** compatibility mode) - проблема исчезла.

Даже без установки "*образа диска дополнительной гостевой ОС*" - нет ползунков и всё работает отлично!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй доустановить *virtualbox-guest-source* и *virtualbox-guest-additions*. А ещё попробуй поменять тип ОС в виртуалбоксе с просто *Linux_64* на *Ubuntu_64*. Про перезагрузку гостя тоже не забудь.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в меню "Вид" окна VirtualBox выбрать пункт "Подгонять размер экрана гостевой ОС"
(по крайней мере у меня он отмечен).